# list workflow 2010 start on change

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, list, workflow

Why can I only select start workflow when items is created. 
I need the option on change.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Translation problem maybee? Aren't the two last checkbox labels translated exactly the same?

Comment: That is a possibility! I will look into that. thanks

Comment: It is a translation problem. The workflow is working. Stupid that I not checked that. Thanks :D

Comment: I've added it at as answer. Too bad there is a lack in the quality of the translation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation problem maybee?

The two last checkbox labels translated exactly the same, so one of them should be the option you are looking for.